# Magento Observer for remove item button cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to do an observer for the remove item button in the cart
i tried to do a `sales_quote_remove_item` event but it does't work !

config.xml

```
       <events>
            <sales_quote_remove_item>
                <observers>
                    <Am_Ir_observer>
                        <class>Am_Ir/ObserverRemoveItemButton</class>
                        <method>removeItem_button</method>
                    </Am_Ir_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_remove_item>
        </events>
```

Observer.php

```
class Am_Ir_Model_ObserverRemoveItemButton {
    public function removeItem_button(Varient_Event_Observer $observer) {

     //some condition...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your module configured correctly? If you call `var_dump(get_class(Mage::getModel('Am_Ir/ObserverRemoveItemButton')))` does it show you `Am_Ir_Model_ObserverRemoteItemButton`? As a general rule of thumb it's probably not a good idea to have underscores in your vendor/package e.g. Am_Ir since the autoloader will interpret the underscore as a new folder and look for Am/Ir/Model/ObserverRemoveItemButton.php

Comment: Now it works :) , actually I checked the underscores and also I had a mistake in my condition. it's perfect now .I thank you for your help !

Comment: Now I have a problem in my code . I made some condition to set some field in a database when the event triggers  (on click on remove item) in a cart .
Now my code is valid only when there is only one product in the cart, for example if i remove the first product, my condition changes the second instead the first.
I need a foreach some think like this but I dont know how to implement it.
here is my condition

Comment: $Mysession = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
$sku = $Mysession->getData("mysku");
$string="removed";
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');         
$query = ("UPDATE  table SET status ='".$string."' WHERE mysku ='".$sku."'");
$writeConnection->query($query);

Comment: What you're doing is horribly bad practice. If you want to remove an item from your cart with an observer, do it using Magento models. If you add all this stuff to your question with a proper explanation of what you want to achieve I might be able to help you out

Comment: simply I want when I click on the remove item button in cart ,i Change a status of this item in a database from 'active' to 'removed' . The request that i posted befor works but he dont change me the right item.

Comment: Where are you storing that status? In a custom table? Why don't you make it a quote attribute or something similar?

Comment: Yes in a custom table, and i have almost all.  id item, sku, status, date ...

Comment: Put all of this detail in your question

Comment: name table: tab 1
attributs: id(auto incremente), customer_id, sku, status, created, updated.